# Simple C evaluation is turning out wrong

Tags: c

I am stuck with a simple thing but unable to explain the reason for it. 
Example code scenario is

```
int e = 0x0000a8e7;
int t = 0xffffffff;
```

`if (e < t)` is evaluating to false. Clearly `e` is +ve and `t` is -1 and hence `e < t` should evaluate to false. Why is it still turning to be true. Any ideas ?

Thanks,

Comment: can you elaborate which assumption is wrong ?

Comment: What actually gets stored in `t` ? I guess the compiler could be clamping `t` and not setting the sign bit - that would be another set of assumptions.

Comment: that value of -1 for t is intentional and e is being calculated from a valid use case.

Comment: I assigned t as -1 and when i see the values in non-hex mode they show t as -1 and e as some high +ve number

Comment: A quick test on http://ideone.com/gSxbWR shows that `e < t` is false which is what you'd expect when `e` is positive and `t` is negative - a positive value is not smaller than a negative value.

Comment: Paste all your code. Add information on what machine are you working.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea. What size is your `int`? Check it by printing out `sizeof(int)`.

You make assumption that your `int` is 32 bit, but if it is 16-bit you overflow `t` and what happens then is implementation defined, so every machine may work this out differently, and yours did something that made `e<t` while mine didn't.

Comment: `0xffffffff` is too big for a 32-bit int too.

Comment: See C99 section 6.7.8 paragraph 11 for the relevant rule on initialisation, and 6.3.1.3 paragraph 3 for the part about assigning to signed integer types. This shows that assigning a value that is too large to fit into an integer type is *implementation* defined.

Answer (score 1):

There are two alternatives:

- `sizeof(int) > 4`

  (43239 < 4294967295) == true
- `sizeof(int) == 2`, where this particular implementation defined behavior occurs

  ( -22297 < -1) == true

Answer (score 1):

You could be encountering *implementation-defined* behaviour. This means that your code is legal but that each implementation (i.e. each compiler) may perform in different ways. Here are the relevant excerpts from the C specification:

> #### Section 6.7.8 paragraph 11
>
> The initializer for a scalar shall be a single expression, optionally enclosed in braces. The initial value of the object is that of the expression (after conversion); the same type constraints and conversions as for simple assignment apply, taking the type of the scalar to be the unqualified version of its declared type.
>
> #### Section 6.3.1.3 paragraph 3
>
> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

If, in your implementation, `int` is 32-bit, then `0xffffffff` is too large to fit into a 32-bit int (which can hold up to 2,147,483,647, but `0xffffffff` = 4,294,967,295).

Comment: I don't get that 0xffffffff can't fit in 32-bit variable.

Comment: `0xffffffff` can't fit in a 32 bit **signed** variable, so by the somewhat complicated definition of constants in C, it has an unsigned type.

Comment: @JensGustedt: not `unsigned int`, but `long int` (well, at least that's what I gather from the table in 6.4.4.1 paragraph 5.

Comment: @dreamlax, no I don't think so. If `unsigned` is 32 bit wide (and `int` is 31 value bits plus sign) the first fit rule applies and `0xffffffff` is of that type.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Oh quite right, it is a hexadecimal constant, but if it were just a decimal constant it would be `long int` (according to the table).

Comment: @dreamlax, yes exactly. In any case it puts it into the domain of implementation defined behavior.